# Is there an equivalent to anyInt(), anyString(), etc. for checking a parameter is of a particular (non-generic) type?

Tags: mockito

If a mocked method is passed a generic type as a parameter, it is easy to generate the same response regardless of its value by using methods such as `anyInt()`, `anyChar()`, `anyString()`, etc.

Is it possible to do this where the parameter must be a particular type of Object?

(For example, `anyCar()`, `anyVehicle()`, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matcher `isA(Class<T> clazz)` provides this functionality.

For example -

`isA(Car.class)`, `isA(Vehicle.class)`